# In every cell of a $9\times 9$ board a positive integer was written.

Tags: combinatorics

In every cell of a $9\times 9$ board a positive integer was written. Then for every row and every column of this board the sum of all its entries was calculated. Is it possible that the $18$ calculated sums are consecutive integers?

I tried to find an example.
But I think there's some technic by which we can prove that it's impossible.
Please give me a hint.

Comment: Hint:  the sum of any $18$ consecutive integers is odd.

Comment: Thanks I solved this problem.